# The namE attribute is not supported in this context

Tags: .net, vb.net, edmx, name-attribute

While i open .EDMX in Visual Studio 2012 means when i click on it, it gives me error like:

> The namE attribute is not supported in this context.

and the same error i get in other application/projects also, this happen only with edmx file not other files.
Can anyone give me solution for this?

Comment: What is "load EDMX"? What steps do you take to load it? Where does the EDMX come from? Did it work before? Did you change anything? On what line of XML or code does Visual Studio give you this error? When does it do so, at design-time or at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solved

I am using `EntityFramework 6.0` version instead of 5.0.

I fixed it by downloading the dll of `EntityFramework 5.0` and remove reference of `EntityFramework 6.0` in my Project and give it again reference of `EntityFramework 5.0 dll` and finally clean and rebuild the project which solved my problem.

Still if anyone get error just try to repair `VisualStudio` and still give you an error just reinstall/new-install your visual studio by running the setup.